# How to create a new alert rule in Azure using PowerShell?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell, azure-cli

I am going nuts here. How in the world can I create a new alert rule in Azure using PowerShell?

With Azure CLI it's as easy as this

```
# Retrieve id for scope parameter
az vm show -n vm1 -o tsv --query id 

# Create action group
az monitor action-group create -n action-group1 -g rg-training --action email admin adminaddress@host.org

# Create alert
az monitor metrics alert create -n alert2 -g rg-training --scopes "/subscriptions/<guid>/resourceGroups/rg-training/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/vm1" --condition "avg Percentage CPU > 90" --window-size 5m --evaluation-frequency 1m --action action-group1 --description "High CPU"
```

This is what my PowerShell attempts look like

```
Import-Module Az.Monitor

# Create a new condition
$condition = New-AzMetricAlertRuleV2Criteria -MetricName "Percentage CPU" -MetricNameSpace "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines" -TimeAggregation Average -Operator GreaterThan -Threshold 5

# Create new action group and receiver
$receiver = New-AzActionGroupReceiver -Name "Admin" -EmailReceiver -EmailAddress "admin@host.org"
Set-AzActionGroup -Name "my-action-group" -ShortName "ActionGroup1" -ResourceGroupName "rg-training" -Receiver $receiver

# Retrieve resource id from vm1
$resourceID = get-azresource -name vm1 | Select-Object resourceid

# Finally add the alert rule that will trigger when for more then 5 min CPU percentage is more then 10%
Add-AzMetricAlertRuleV2 -Name "metricRule2" -ResourceGroupName "rg-training" -WindowSize 00:05:00 -Frequency 00:01:00 -TargetResourceId $resourceID -Condition $condition -ActionGroupId "my-action-group" -Severity 4
```

Which results in

```
> Add-AzMetricAlertRuleV2 : Exception type: ErrorResponseException,
> Message: Null/Empty, Code: Null, Status code:BadRequest, Reason
> phrase: Bad Request At C:\Temp\03 Create and test alerts.ps1:17 char:1
> + Add-AzMetricAlertRuleV2 -Name "metricRule2" -ResourceGroupName "rg-tr ...
> + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Add-AzMetricAlertRuleV2], PSInvalidOperationException
> + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Insights.Alerts.AddAzureRmMetricAlertRuleV2Command
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Which version of azure cli are you using?

Comment: Thx for replying. Don't know why this would be relevant, but here you go `2.5.1`

Comment: You are right, I meant az powershell version - `Get-InstalledModule -name az` according to this thread: https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/9259#issuecomment-499108597 This bug have fixed for version 3.X

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have figured it out in the meantime... the culprit was the way I retrieved `$targetResourceId`. The following worked for me...

```
# TypeName: Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Insights.OutputClasses.PSActionGroupResource
$actionGroup = Get-AzActionGroup -Name "my-action-group" -ResourceGroupName "rg-training" 

# TypeName: Microsoft.Azure.Management.Monitor.Management.Models.ActivityLogAlertActionGroup
$actionGroupId = New-AzActionGroup -ActionGroupId $actionGroup.Id

# TypeName: System.TimeSpan
$windowSize = New-TimeSpan -Minutes 1

# TypeName: System.TimeSpan
$frequency = New-TimeSpan -Minutes 1 

# TypeName: Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Insights.OutputClasses.PSMetricCriteria
$condition = New-AzMetricAlertRuleV2Criteria -MetricName "Percentage CPU" -TimeAggregation Average -Operator GreaterThan -Threshold 0.1

# TypeName: System.String
$targetResourceId = (Get-AzResource -Name VM1).ResourceId

# TypeName: Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Profile.Models.Core.PSAzureContext
$context = Get-AzContext

Add-AzMetricAlertRuleV2 -Name "metricRule" -ResourceGroupName "rg-training" -WindowSize $windowSize -Frequency $frequency -TargetResourceId $targetResourceId -Condition $condition -ActionGroup $actionGroupId -Severity 3
```

You can read more about it [here](https://www.azureblue.io/how-to-create-an-alert-rule-using-powershell-and-azure-cli/)